# how do i implement quantity in add to cart functionality?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building an eCommerce store and ran into a problem :
[image]

this is my cart component I want to make it so if the item is the same just change the quantity of the item, I don't want it to display the same item.

I've tried using an if-else block to change the quantity but didn't come up with a good solution.

the function i use to update the selected size is this:

```
  const updateSelectedSize=(item,selectedSize)=>{
        item.size=selectedSize;
        return item;
    
      }
```

the function I use to add items to the cart is this:

```
const handleAddtoCart=(item,selectedSize)=>{


 const  updatedItem=updateSelectedSize(item,selectedSize);
 

 let  newitemArray=[...cart,updatedItem]
  setcart(newitemArray)


 
}
```

here is what a sample of the product data looks like:

```
{
      id: 1,
      title: "Hypervenom Phinish 'Volt'",
      price: "200",
      SizinginNumbers: true,
      img: "https://image.goat.com/transform/v1/attachments/product_template_pictures/images/013/255/557/original/749901_703.png.png?action=crop&width=950",
      color: "#cfeb30",
      size: null,
      itemcolor: null,
      catagory: "soccer",
    }
```

this is the compenent that excutes the add to cart function :

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const ShoeProductCard = ({ productData,handleAddtoCart }) => {
  const [selectedSize, setSelectedSize] = useState(null);

  const sizes = [7, 8, 9, 10];
  
  return productData.map((product) => {
    return (
      <div key={product.id} className="productsGrid">
        <div key={product.id} className="container">
          <div

            key={product.id}
            style={{ backgroundColor: product.color }}
            className="card"
          >
 lastly    <div key={product.id} className="imgBx">
              <img key={product.id} src={product.img} alt="shoes" />
            </div>
            <div className="contentBx">
              <h2>{product.title}</h2>
              <div className="size">
                <h3>Size :</h3>
                {sizes.map((size) => (
                  <button
                    onClick={() => {
                      setSelectedSize(size);
                    }}
                    className="sizebutton"
                    style={{
                      margin: ".5rem",
                      width: "2rem",
                      height: "2rem",
                      borderRadius: "1rem",
                      border: "none",
                      backgroundColor:
                        selectedSize === size ? "black" : "white",

                      color: selectedSize === size ? "white" : "black",
                    }}
                    key={size}
                  >
                    {size}
                  </button>
                ))}
              </div>

              <a href="#" alt="logo">
                {" "}
                <i onClick={()=>{handleAddtoCart(product,selectedSize)}}className="fa-solid fa-cart-arrow-down"></i>
              </a>
              <br />
              <span className="price">Price: {product.price}</span>
              <br />
              <i 
                style={{ color: "white", cursor: "pointer" }}
                className="fa-solid fa-circle-info"
              ></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
};

export default ShoeProductCard;
```

lastly, this is the cart component :

```
import React from "react";

const Cart = ({ cart, removeItem }) => {
  return (
    <div className="box">
      {cart.length === 0 ? (
        <h1 style={{ color: "white" }}>none</h1>
      ) : (
        cart.map((item) => {
          return (
            <>
              <div class="shopping-cart">
                <div class="title">{item.title}</div>

                <div class="item">
                  <div class="buttons">
                    <button class="delete-btn"></button>
                  </div>

                  <div class="image">
                    <img id="cartimage" src={item.img} alt="" />
                  </div>

                  <div class="description">
                    <span>Size:</span>
                    <span>{item.size}</span>
                  </div>

                  <div class="quantity">
                    <button className="quantity-btn">-</button>
                    <span>{0}</span>
                    <button className="quantity-btn">+</button>
                  </div>

                  <div class="total-price">$549</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br />
            </>
          );
        })
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

I want a way that if the item is the same increase the quantity if not then render the item as is.

Comment: So in the code instead of just adding another item see if it’s already there and increment?

Comment: should I add a quantity property to the data and then just render that out? so every time an item is the same I just increase that property by one?